# Design custom cell size table with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am trying to design table with custom cell sizes with bootstrap using `grid system` concept; following mock-up may help what I am trying to achieve.

---

|________|_________________|_____________|______________|
|________|______________________________________________|
|_____________|_________________________________________|
|______________________|________________________________|
|__________|___________________|_________|______________|

html:

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
    <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-2">Voucher Number</td>
        <td class="col-xs-2 text-left">13303</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4 text-right">Date of issue</td>
        <td class="col-xs-4 text-left">Dec 12, 2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Name of Patient</td>
        <td class="col-xs-9 text-left">Muhammad Umair</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but it breaks in design view; like this
[image]

I am not getting the point why this show irregular look.

Comment: Hmm, when you use those class's in the header it effects the rows below as well (which is good obviously). I dunno if and how you can overwrite it per line. maybe `colspan` works here? haven't used it in years

Comment: @LiranBo is this thing is possible which I want to achieve.

Comment: You can manipulate it. just create 12 cells and use the colspan

Answer (score 0):

not a pretty sight, but if you really need it - [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LiranBo/kskp2npc/2/)

**HTML** - notice the first hidden row (defines all cells sizes)

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
    <tr class="hidden">
        <th class="col-xs-1"></th>
        <th class="col-xs-1"></th>
        <th class="col-xs-1"></th>
        <th class="col-xs-1"></th>
        <th class="col-xs-1"></th>
        <th class="col-xs-1"></th>
        <th class="col-xs-1"></th>
        <th class="col-xs-1"></th>
        <th class="col-xs-1"></th>
        <th class="col-xs-1"></th>
        <th class="col-xs-1"></th>
        <th class="col-xs-1"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Voucher Number</th>
        <th colspan="4">13303</th>
        <th colspan="4">Date of issue</th>
        <th colspan="2">Dec 12, 2015</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">val1</td>
        <td colspan="10">val2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Name of Patient</td>
        <td colspan="3">Name of Patient</td>
        <td colspan="3">Muhammad Umair</td>
        <td colspan="4">Muhammad Umair</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS** - just to highlight borders

```
td, th{
    border: solid;
}
```

This is defiantly a workaround, there might be a better way.

**Notice:** the `colspan` which basically merges adject cells.